# How to add letter spacing to drop down options?

Tags: css

I would like to add letter spacing to the drop down options. Only the highlighted text seems to be working fine not the options.

[[image: screen shot]]

Here is my code:

```
.uDDL select
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue LT 47 LightCn', 'HelveticaLightCondensed', Sans-         Serif;
    top: 11px;
    right: 15%;
    border: 0px;
    outline: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 29px;
    width: 296px;
    background: transparent;
    padding-left: 39px;
}
.DDL select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
.uDDL option 
{
    font-family: HelveticaLightCondensed;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have made your image inline.  Please edit the question and post your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not calling the elements correctly so try to check your css combination again. Also if you want more help, post your CSS and HTML code along with anything that you have tried.